# Why upstream task does not failover if it encounters a network problem

Tags: apache-flink

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestQueue Flink Netty Server (0) Thread 1                              [] - Encountered error while consuming partitions
org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection timed out
```

When the task encounters this exception, it stops sending data but does not failover.
Why the upstream task status does not switch to failed when encountering network problems.